# CodeIgniter - Search function (products->category_id database relationship)

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code:

```
function search($terms){
    $query      = $this->db->get_where('products',"name LIKE '%$terms%' OR description LIKE '%$terms%'");
    $product    = $query->result_array();

    foreach($product as $p):            
        $query2 = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('cat_id' => $p['prod_category']));
        $category   = $query2->row_array();

        $product['category'] = $category['cat_link'];
    endforeach;

    return $product;
}
```

in my search function.  It will return something like:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
   [prod_id] => 5
   [prod_name] => Product
   [prod_category] => 1
)
```

But what I'm after is:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
   [prod_id] => 5
   [prod_name] => Product
   [prod_category] => Category1
)
```

from the name of my category with the id 1. This is in my 'categories' table. The foreach loop is not the right way to accomplish this, but what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your search logic by letting your database handle the joining of your tables.

```
function search($terms){

    $this->db->select('prod_id, prod_name, cat_name');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'cat_id = prod_category', 'inner');
    $this->db->like('name', $terms);
    $this->db->or_like('description', $terms);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

This is assuming your category name column is named `cat_name`.  The results would be as follow :

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
   [prod_id] => 5
   [prod_name] => Product
   [cat_name] => Category1
)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method:

I'm assuming that you've already loaded your libraries

**CONTROLLER**

```
function search()
{
$data['query'] = $this->Books_model->get_search();
$this->load->view(‘books’, $data);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function get_search()
{
$match = $this->input->post(‘search’);
$this->db->like(‘bookname’,$match);
$this->db->or_like(‘author’,$match);
$this->db->or_like(‘characters’,$match);
$this->db->or_like(‘synopsis’,$match);
$query = $this->db->get(‘books’);
return $query->result();
}
```

**VIEWS**

```
<?=form_open(‘books/search’);?>
<?php $search = array(‘name’=>’search’,'id’=>’search’,'value’=>”,);?>
<?=form_input($search);?><input type=submit value=’Search’ /></p>
<?=form_close();?>
```

The result can be displayed using a HTML table

```
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Book</th><th>Author</th><th>Published</th><th>Price</th></tr>
<?php foreach($query as $item):?>
<tr>
<td><?= $item->id ?></td>
<td><?= $item->bookname ?></td>
<td><?= $item->author ?></td>
<td><?= $item->datepublished ?></td>
<td><?= $item->price ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

This is what I'm using and I hope it'll help you to make search function on Code Igniter.

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is the relationship between the products prod_category and the categorys category_id. :)